# How do you punctuate a list of lists of names?

Tags: punctuation

I am not sure how to punctuate this sentence (the punctuation below is my best guess):

> We refer to the classical research of Oleinik-Petrovsky, Thom and Milnor.

How it should be understood: The original research was a collaboration of two researchers, Oleinik and Petrovsky. Two additional papers were published independently later, one by Thom and one by Milnor.

Comment: The standard way is to use semicolons: "the classical research of Oleinik and Petrovsky; Thom; and Milnor." In this case, you can avoid semicolons by saying "the classical research of Oleinik and Petrovsky, of Thom, and of Milnor."

Comment: I can't see any reason not to use two commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having reference numbers would help you indicate these are three separate papers:

*We refer to the classical research of Oleinik-Petrovsky **[6]**, Thom **[8]**, and Milnor **[17]**.*

without doing changes to the punctuation.

BTW, an **Oxford comma** is indicated before "and."